# what is the use refs/for/refs/* in gerrit?

Tags: gerrit

Trying to understand refs/for/refs/* feature in gerrit. This question is not about refs/for/master.

1. when can we use this refs/for/refs/* feature.
2. Could some one explain best use case for this.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/concept-refs-for-namespace.html) the refs/for/* syntax is just a short name for refs/for/refs/*:

> Gerrit supports using either the full name or the short name for a branch. For instance, this command:
>
> `git commit`
>
> `git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master`
>
> is the same as:
>
> `git commit`
>
> `git push origin HEAD:refs/for/refs/heads/master`

Whether you use one or the other is up to you. Since other examples in the documentation use the "refs/for/*" form, you might want to stick to that.

Answer (score -1):

**refs/for/refs/***  in Gerrit permission allows users to push their commits for Gerrit review.

example:

git push origin HEAD:refs/for/some_branch